# MyPlugin::createJSAPI only being called after a js interaction

Tags: javascript, lifecycle, firebreath

I've noticed that the call to the `createJSAPI` method in my plugin is only called after I somehow try to interact with the actual DOM element.

Is there a way to make it happen before any javascript interaction is happening?
In the documentation for `getRootJSAPI` it states:

> It is not recommended to call this from the constructor or before
>   setHost is called, as many JSAPI objects need the BrowserHost and a
>   weak_ptr to the Plugin class to function correctly

So when is it appropriate to call this method? in `onPluginReady` or `onWindowAttached`?

Thanks.

---

Edit

This is my createJSAPI code:

```
FB::JSAPIPtr plugin::createJSAPI()
{
    this->jsApi = JSApiPtr(new pluginAPI(FB::ptr_cast<plugin>(shared_from_this()), m_host));
    return this->jsApi;
}
```

And this is the onPluginReady code:

```
void plugin::onPluginReady()
{
    this->getRootJSAPI();
    this->jsApi->fireMyEvent(this->myId);
}
```

and the event isn't fired, though this does:

```
bool plugin::onMouseDown(FB::MouseDownEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow *)
{
    this->jsApi->fireMyEvent(this->myId);
    return false;
}
```

Why is that?

As for the build in onload mechanism, I need my own, since I need to pass some parameters to that fired event.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this method during or after `onPluginReady` -- that's one of the main purposes of the function.

EDIT:

To answer your further question, onPluginReady is likely to be called before your onLoad callback from the param tag gets called; that means your event handlers aren't attached yet.  That's the reason that FireBreath provides the onload param callback -- it gives you a place to attach event handlers and find out that things are loaded.

Comment: Thanks. Another question though, when I try to fire an event right after the call to my `createJSAPI` it doesn't work, while debugging it I noticed that there are no proxies to fire the event on. But if I have the exact same code in the mouse down event then the event is fired as it should. When does the js api object finishes it's initialization? Can I be informed of when I can fire events?  For example, if I want to fire my own loaded event as the plugin finishes loading. Thanks.

Comment: You can do this stuff during or after onPluginReady -- that's one of the main purposes of the function.

Comment: note that for a loaded event you should use the onload param as shown in the examples (see examples/FBTestPlugin/test.html)

Comment: rather than edit your original question to be a different one, it would be better to ask a new question -- for future reference

Comment: Noted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854788/how-to-fire-events-when-plugin-is-loaded