# How to fire events when plugin is loaded

Tags: javascript, events, firebreath

In my plugin I need to be able to fire event(s) once the plugin was loaded.
I don't want to use the built in mechanism (adding it in the object params) since I need to be able to control the parameters which are sent along with the event firing.

The problem is that when I try to fire the event in `onPluginReady` it just doesn't fire.. While debugging I noticed that the `m_proxies` is empty (in `JSAPIImpl::FireEvent`), but if I try the same code for firing the event in the `onMouseDown` method then it works well.

This is my createJSAPI code:

```
FB::JSAPIPtr plugin::createJSAPI()
{
    this->jsApi = JSApiPtr(new pluginAPI(FB::ptr_cast<plugin>(shared_from_this()), m_host));
    return this->jsApi;
}
```

And this is the onPluginReady code:

```
void plugin::onPluginReady()
{
    this->getRootJSAPI();
    this->jsApi->fireMyEvent(this->myId);
}
```

and the event isn't fired, though this does:

```
bool plugin::onMouseDown(FB::MouseDownEvent *evt, FB::PluginWindow *)
{
    this->jsApi->fireMyEvent(this->myId);
    return false;
}
```

Why is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onPluginReady is likely to be called before your onLoad callback from the param tag gets called; that means your event handlers aren't attached yet. That's the reason that FireBreath provides the onload param callback -- it gives you a place to attach event handlers and find out that things are loaded.

**Edit to clarify from comments:**

The callback will be provided with a single parameter which contains a reference to your root JSAPI object.  Note that in this case it is *not* the object or embed tag, just the JSAPI object, so you can use any methods or properties from there.

Comment: So, basically the way to do what I want is to use the onload param callback, then have my js invoke a method (or read a readonly property) on the plugin to get the needed data?

Comment: This is problematic since I will have a few plugin instances in the same page. For each such instance I have a js object which has a loaded method (among others) which should be called when the plugin has loaded. This method is binded to the js object (scope wise), and I don't have a name of a method to pass to the plugin with the `onload` param. I can of course create a temporary js function, pass the name and then remove it after it was called in order to associate onload of a certain plugin with a js object, but that's far from being ideal. any other ideas?

Comment: You have a chicken and egg problem here -- you can't attach the event listener until after the plugin loads.  There are lots of ways you can address this; you could use a unique id for each instance that you use to determine which it is, you could set another param with an id to remember, you could use different functions for each onload... plenty of options.  However, you can't attach an event listener until after it has loaded.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution, turns out that the js onload callback receives one parameter which is the jsapi, I just added a readonly property to that which returns the unique id, with that I can then find the relevant instance and let it know it's loaded. However, I discovered that by accident, the examples don't show that.. Is it documented?

Comment: Hmm; it might not be.  Feel free to add it to the website! (it's a wiki)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is being passed to the js callback, when I printed it to the console it showed an object which had another readonly property I've defined, and so I assumed I can use that. But on the firebreath implementation I have no clue, if you can elaborate on that I would love to know.